# change href to redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I use below code click to change `<a>` `href` attribute to redirect,
the reason I don't want use `window.location`, `window.open`,
because if I use this method, when user click the button they can still **choose press keyboard open new url in tab or not**

in example `a` it works as usual, but `b` only change href
not redirect, why? and how to fix?

```
<div class="submit">
  <a>submit</a>
</div>
```

a

```
$('.submit').on('click', function() {
  var submit = $(this);

  // var url = ...;
  $(submit).find('a').attr('href', url);
});
```

b

```
$('.submit').on('click', function() {
var submit = $(this);

  requestPost().then(function(response) {  
    // ... 

    // var url = ...;
    $(submit).find('a').attr('href', url);
  });
});
```

Comment: "Open in a new tab" is important browser functionality. You shouldn't rob it from your users unless you have a **very** good reason.

Comment: ?? ya I agree that is important , thats why I ask this question.  try to find way, I can use ajax post data and user still can choose open with tab or not, not just use window.open and decide for user.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in `a` you are assigning a `href` in the `onclick` handler of the `anchor`'s container, which means that the click event won't complete until onclick handler is complete (because this handler has the capability to abort click and navigation by just returning `false` or doing a `event.preventDefault`).

While in `b` because you are using an asynchronous function, the onclick handler completes successfully before the async function `requestPost` is completed, so changing the `href` of the anchor doesn't have the navigation affect because onclick has already completed with no href tag, however if you click again on `submit` then it would navigate because `href` was set in previous click.

So as a quick workaround, what you can do is trigger a click on anchor after you assign href attribute, like

`$(submit).find('a').attr('href', url).click();`

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried trigger click before, but it will post data again, infinite loop

Comment: right then do one thing, at the end of `$('.submit').on('click', function() {` return false, let me try to attach a snippet to my answer, if SO supports navigation

Comment: a check can be made on the tagName in this case, but anyways, you are right about the flawed process, the thing is that he wants the user to decide if he has to open in new tab or in the current tab or in a new window.